# How to configure rsyslog to send multiple logs to a remote server and save them as individual files?

Tags: linux, centos, logging, rsyslog

I have some log files inside a directory called `log`

```
ls -l /var/log/

org1_app.log  org2_app.log  org1_perf.log org2_perf.log  ...
```

Now I set up an `rsyslog client` on the host server. Here is the configuration below

```
# rsyslog configuration file

# For more information see /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-*/rsyslog_conf.html
# If you experience problems, see http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/troubleshoot.html

#### MODULES ####

# The imjournal module below is now used as a message source instead of imuxsock.
$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command)
$ModLoad imjournal # provides access to the systemd journal
#$ModLoad imklog # reads kernel messages (the same are read from journald)
#$ModLoad immark  # provides --MARK-- message capability

# Provides UDP syslog reception
#$ModLoad imudp
#$UDPServerRun 514

# Provides TCP syslog reception
$ModLoad imtcp
$InputTCPServerRun 514


#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####

# Where to place auxiliary files
$WorkDirectory /var/lib/rsyslog

# Use default timestamp format
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

# File syncing capability is disabled by default. This feature is usually not required,
# not useful and an extreme performance hit
#$ActionFileEnableSync on

# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf

# Turn off message reception via local log socket;
# local messages are retrieved through imjournal now.
$OmitLocalLogging on

# File to store the position in the journal
$IMJournalStateFile imjournal.state


#### RULES ####

# Log all kernel messages to the console.
# Logging much else clutters up the screen.
#kern.*                                                 /dev/console

# Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.
# Don't log private authentication messages!
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages

# The authpriv file has restricted access.
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure

# Log all the mail messages in one place.
mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog


# Log cron stuff
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron

# Everybody gets emergency messages
*.emerg                                                 :omusrmsg:*

# Save news errors of level crit and higher in a special file.
uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler

# Save boot messages also to boot.log
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log


# ### begin forwarding rule ###
# The statement between the begining ... end define a SINGLE forwarding
# rule. They belong together, do NOT split them. If you create multiple
# forwarding rules, duplicate the whole block!
# Remote Logging (we use TCP for reliable delivery)
#
# An on-disk queue is created for this action. If the remote host is
# down, messages are spooled to disk and sent when it is up again.
#$ActionQueueFileName fwdRule1 # unique name prefix for spool files
#$ActionQueueMaxDiskSpace 1g   # 1gb space limit (use as much as possible)
#$ActionQueueSaveOnShutdown on # save messages to disk on shutdown
#$ActionQueueType LinkedList   # run asynchronously
#$ActionResumeRetryCount -1    # infinite retries if host is down
# remote host is: name/ip:port, e.g. 192.168.0.1:514, port optional
#*.* @@remote-host:514
# ### end of the forwarding rule ###
#*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none @@xx.xx.xx.xx:514


$ModLoad imfile
$InputFileName /var/log/org*.log
$InputFileTag dev-log
$InputFileStateFile stat-dev-log
$InputFileSeverity error
$InputFileFacility local3
$InputFilePollInterval 10
$InputRunFileMonitor
local3.* @@xx.xx.xx.xx:514
```

After restarting rsyslog, the logs are being sent and received in the remote server inside `/var/log/messages`

But the problem is all these logs are getting mixed up. What I want is that each of these log files should be created separately in the remote server and then the subsequent logs are added in those respective log files.

I did look up for some resources but couldn't find any answer that satisfies my requirement. The closest I found was this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59861378/issue-with-multiple-logs-files-forwarding-with-rsyslog but it involves manually defining each log file but in my case there will be a many log files and I can't manually define every single one of them in the `rsyslog.conf` file.

How do I ensure multiple log files data are not mixed together inside `/var/log/messages` but rather a separate file is created for each one of them and the subsequent updates go into those respective files?

Comment: How can you differentiate which logs belong to which file? Is there an id or a specific string in a message?

Answer (score 0):

(Trivial answer, but I can't comment yet) You may try more tagging https://www.gilesorr.ca/blog/rsyslog-intermediate-local.html or see Filter Conditions: https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/filters.html